# How to create link to cell of one worksheet from another worksheet of same file in open office calc?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have two calc worksheets in open office, Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Sheet1 having columns, EmployeeID EmployeeDesignation
Sheet2 having columns, EmployeeID Link

Once user click on Link cell of Sheet2 for particular row, based on  EmployeeID match user should re-direct to EmployeeDesignation cell of Sheet2 having same EmployeeID.

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet2 select a link cell, click on the hyperlink icon

[image: hyperlink icon]

and for *Target* enter:

```
Sheet1.B2
```

(where `B2` represents the appropriate cell reference to jump to) and then click <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

If you have a lot to do you might want to apply Basic.